# Why is it that I keep getting the error Insufficient 'DISKS_TOTAL_GB' quota when trying to create cluster on google cloud console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bigdata, google-compute-engine, cluster-computing, google-cloud-dataproc

I keep getting the error Insufficient 'DISKS_TOTAL_GB' quota when I try create a compute engine cluster on google cloud console. It is strange because I have no disks that are active. All the disks related to the cluster are usually deleted whenever I delete the cluster.

I check my quota, it is saying that 90% of the persistent disk quota has been reached which I find odd because I didn't create any disks otherwise. I also checked the compute engine disks and none appear to be there. I don't need a quota increase because I have over 4000gb space allocated to the Persistent disk already and I am usually well below that amount. Additionally, when I create a cluster with persistent disk with space below the amount which is proposed as the limit, the cluster fails and the limit gets less. I also enabled billing a while back so you can cross that off your list. That still persists even after I delete the faulty cluster. Can I get some help please? This is related to my final assignment and I am so close to finishing.

Comment: You mention `space allocated to the Persistent disk already and I am usually well below that amount`. If you create a 4 TB disk, it does not matter how little you use of that disk. You have used 4 TB of your persistent disk quota. Your post has lots of words, but no details (facts). Look up your quotas in the Google Cloud Console. Edit your post and show what is already consumed and the total quota. You also mention deleting resources. Depending on what you had and what you did, it may take time before that consumed quota is released to be used again.

Comment: The resources were released after some time. Thanks John

Comment: OK, but please update your question so that a good answer can be made. We do not want questions left open and unanswerable.